# PowerShell Script to Monitor Files & Run Script

Tags: file, powershell, directory, monitoring, readonly-attribute

I'm looking for a script which can monitor a Folder that has lots of .DAT files and as soon as new .DAT file is added the script can run to change the file attribute of these files to read-only format.

I have made the script to change the file format of these files, but I need your help guys help me create the script to monitor this Folder as soon as new file is created.

```
$Path = Get-Childitem -Path D:\ReadOnly\* 
foreach ($Item in $Path) {
  Set-ItemProperty $Path -Name IsReadOnly -Value $True
}
```

Comment: Hello Guys, what if I use the modified date of the folder. If the last modified date is less than today's date, apply the ReadOnly script..

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Register-ObjectEvent](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849929.aspx).

However, you can just run in a loop with a little delay (which you will probably need regardless, because otherwise your script will just exit immediately) and re-check. Or run the script regularly via the Task Scheduler. Or write a little C# program to do the same (which will be easier to write because .NET object events are awkward in PowerShell).

Comment: Ah, I copied before my forced redirect kicked in. If I could tell Google to never, *ever* send me to the German MSDN, I'd love to ...

Answer (score 0):

Task scheduler is probably cleaner, but if you want, this should do it with a never ending while statement(modify sleep time as desired):

```
while (1) {$Path = Get-Childitem -Path D:\ReadOnly\* 
foreach ($Item in $Path) {
  Set-ItemProperty $Path -Name IsReadOnly -Value $True ; start-sleep -Seconds 5
}}
```